# Is there any difference between "what time should I expect your call" and "what time should I be expecting your call"?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-continuous, present-simple

Is there any difference between *what time should I expect your call* and *what time should I be expecting your call*? For example:

> Person A: I'll call you tomorrow and we'll talk about the trip.
>
> Person B: Alright. What time should I expect your call?/What time Should I be expecting your call?

Comment: There is no significant difference. (Of course A would say _I'll call you tomorrow_.)

Comment: To me, the continuous form somehow has a note of expectancy and sounds a bit more polite (but it's probably just me)